# Perl Reg Expressions, word anchor and special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a script to detect variable types and have been having an issue with my regular expression.

```
if(/\$\b([a-zA-Z]|_ )(\w)*\b /x && !/ /)
```

is what I am using to detect a scalar. The problem right now though is that `\b \b` doesn't seem to be working with the special characters (`!@#$`, etc). For example it would count `$var###` as a valid name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you have is correct. all you need to do is to anchor it to the start and end of the string

```
^\$\b([a-zA-Z]|_ )(\w)*\b$
```

example http://regex101.com/r/uD1eR7/1

**Changes made**

- `^` anchors the regex at the start of the string
- `$` anchors the regex at the end of the string

**Note** you can also move the underscore `_` into the character class and remove the word boundaries as it does not give extra advantage

```
^\$[a-zA-Z_]\w*$
```

Comment: @user3889565 You are welcome. You can even have a much simpler regex as in edited answer. also drop the parathesis so that it avoids uneccessary capturing. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R:  You should get rid of the word boundaries, too.  I know they're not hurting anything, but they're not necessary.  By leaving them in, you unintentionally imply that they're doing something useful.

Comment: @AlanMoore Agree with you it does not give any extra added advantage. I have edited the answer